# Access files on Samsung GT-S5230 (Avila)

Tags: mount, automounting, samsung, phone

I'm a new (still new) linux user (Fedora, LXDE).

The phone I currently use is Samsung Avila, or Samsung Star (Samsung GT-S5230, http://www.samsung.com/pl/consumer/mobile-devices/other-phones/others/GT-S5230LKAPLS/, http://www.phonemore.com/samsung-star-gt-s5230/specs/503).

But it seems not to automounts, or I don't know where to look for it in the filesystem.

**Is there a way to access the files on it (just photos), when connected by USB cable?**

I was thinking about `mount`, but had some problems with e.g. finding the name of the device. Also, I would be glad if there is an application.

---

UPDATE 1:

**My `lsblk` output:**

```
NAME                                    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
sda                                       8:0    0 55,9G  0 disk  
├─sda4                                    8:4    0    1K  0 part  
├─sda2                                    8:2    0 41,6G  0 part  
├─sda5                                    8:5    0  3,5G  0 part  
├─sda3                                    8:3    0    1G  0 part /boot  
├─sda1                                    8:1    0  100M  0 part  
└─sda6                                    8:6    0  9,3G  0 part  
  ├─fedora-swap                         253:1    0    1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]  
  ├─fedora-home                         253:4    0  768M  0 lvm  /home  
  ├─fedora-usr                          253:2    0    4G  0 lvm  /usr  
  ├─fedora-root                         253:0    0    1G  0 lvm  /  
  ├─fedora-home_michal_Dokumenty_Dyplom 253:5    0  512M  0 lvm /home/michal/Dokumenty/Dyplom  
  └─fedora-var                          253:3    0    2G  0 lvm  /var
```

---

UPDATE 2:

**The modes that my phone can use to connect to computer:**
1) Media player mode;
2) PC studio mode;
3) Mass storage mode.

---

UPDATE 3:

**`simple-mtpfs` outputs:**

Firstly, I've checked whether `~/mnt` exists.

Secondly, I've checked `simple-mtpfs -l` output: `1: SamsungGT-S5230`.

The additional files that appeared in `/dev` after connecting the phone:
1) Media player mode: `libmtp-1-1`;
2) PC studio mode: `ttyACM3`;
3) Mass storage mode: --- (no additional files).

My outputs for `simple-mtpfs /dev/[file name] ~/mnt`:
1) Media player mode:
1.1) Running the command once: `ERROR: Could not close session!`,
1.2) Running the command twice and so on: `LIBMTP PANIC: Trying to dump the error stack of a NULL device!`;
2) PC studio mode: --- (no output appeared);
3) Mass storage mode: ---.

The same outputs appear for `simple-mtpfs --device 1 ~/mnt`.

---

UPDATE 4:

**`jmtpfs` outputs:**

My outputs for `jmtpfs ~/mnt`:
1) Media player mode:

```
Device 0 (VID=0438 and PID=e20c) is a Samsung GT-S5230.
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attemp to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
terminate called after throwing an instance of ‘MtpErrorCantOpenDevice’
  what(): Can’t open device
Przerwane (zrzut pamięci) [english literally: interrupted (memory dump)]
```

2) PC studio mode: `No mtp devices found.`;
3) Mass storage mode: `No mtp devices found.`.

---

UPDATE 5:

- When I run **`simple-mtpfs`** as **root** in **Media player mode**, it shows the same results if running as user (that is, as above).
- **`jmtpfs -l`** shows the following output:

```
Device 0 (VID=0438 and PID=e20c) is a Samsung GT-S5230.  
Available devices (busLocation, devNum, productId, vendorId, product, vendor):  
1, 10, 0xe20c, 0x04e8, GT-S5230, Samsung
```

- When I run `jmtpfs` for the `mnt` directory in my home directory (Media player mode), it shows only `Device 0 (VID=0438 and PID=e20c) is a Samsung GT-S5230.` output and **there appears an `mnt` volume (?) on the left side of my file manager window (PCManFM)**, as illustrated below:
  [image: mnt in file manager window]
  But when I want to access, **it displays (possible english version): `Error - The specified directory is not valid`.** After clicking OK, it's empty.

What's interesting:
- when I `cd ~/mnt`, it displays (my free translation from Polish) `No access`;
- when I `ls -ld ~/mnt`, it displays `No access to mnt`;
- when I `ls -l ~`, it displays `No access to mnt` and the `mnt` row looks like that: **`d?????????? ? ? ? ? mnt`**.

---

UPDATE 6:

I've tried **`android-tools`** (it uses ADB), as @Stolous suggested in his answer. **My `adb devices` output (in all the three modes):**

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

and then, after `adb devices` again, the output is just: `List of devices attached` and an empty line.

Comment: Add the output of `lsblk` to your question please.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson, here you go.

Comment: Some Samsung devices only allow file access through a protocol, `MTP`, and do not offer the usual "Mass Storage Device" interface. If this is the case, you may need to install additional software to support MTP.

Comment: Also: not all MTP tools support all MTP phones. ArchLinux wiki has [a list of MTP tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mtp#Functionality), you will have to see which one works better with your phone.

Comment: Thanks, @njsg, the list is helpful. I'll give them a try.

Comment: From your output, I guess "media player mode" is MTP. Here, the name `libmtp-...` is created by a `udev` rule installed by `libmtp`. Just to make sure, can you check the permissions on the `libmtp-...` file under `/dev/`? If it is assigned to a group with `rw` permissions, is your user in that group? (You can use e.g. the `groups` command to check your current groups.)

Comment: That said about MTP, if "Mass storage mode" is the regular "pendrive" interface,  you probably want to try to get that one working first. If it does not create any new device file, can you check which lines show up in the kernel log (`dmesg`)  when you plug the phone in its "mass storage mode"? There should be some USB-related messages identifying the device and then, hopefully, some more information about the "storage device".

Comment: *Mass storage mode* probably "means" only the memory card. When I connect via that mode, there is a message **"Insert memory card"** on the phone. I don't have such a card now (although I do realise it could be possible in linux to make a use of it without a card ;-) ). I will check the permissions.

Comment: @njsg, I checked the permissions: the group that the `libmtp-1-1` file is assigned to is **`root`**, and I am **not** assigned to this group.

Comment: If the group (not the user) is `root`, then that's the problem. You could try changing the user ownership of `libmtp-...` to your user and running `jmtpfs mountpoint` again as your user, to see if it works. (This is just a temporary hack — if it works, you'll have to find a persistent way of doing it, as the permissions will be reset next time.) [...]

Comment: [...] Normally, when it works, `jmtpfs mountpoint` only prints the identification of the device. Make sure you unlock your phone (i.e. go past the lock screen) after connecting it to the computer (even if you lock it again afterwards) — at least some Samsung devices don't allow MTP access before you unlock the phone. `ls` before unlocking gives me `ls: cannot access ...: Input/output error`.

Comment: You can [prepend `LC_ALL=C `  to your commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do/87763#87763) in order to get error messages in the default language (most likely some variant of English).

Comment: OK, @njsg, I understand. But, as far as I know, the permissions in Linux are "a bit" powerful - I suppose ownership, too - therefore I wonder: is it OK to change it whenever and wherever one needs it?

Comment: @Michał, permissions and ownership are one of the ways to control access to devices ([some time ago I wrote a bit about that in an answer to another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61456/standard-way-to-expose-device-file-to-userland-applications-running-on-an-unpriv/61521#61521)). Not only it is OK, it is also the way many UNIX systems do it. If you are using `udev` (likely, as I believe `libmtp-1-1` is created by a `udev` rule), you will have to add this as a rule in `udev`, as otherwise changes in permissions and ownership will disappear after a reboot.

Comment: @Michał, the more correct way of doing it would probably be to have `libmtp...` assigned to a group (say, `mtp-devices`, or something more generic such as `plugdev`) and adding your user account to that group. I suggested changing the _user_ ownership as a quick way to check if this would solve the problem.

Comment: OK, @njsg, thanks for the clarification. I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 2):

#### What you need is MTP (Media Transfert Protocol) support.

You can install a tool called *simple-mtpfs* to mount your device storage.

```
dnf install simple-mtpfs
```

Then you will be able to mount it like this:

```
simple-mtpfs /dev/device /media/yourphone
```

Comment: Thanks, @Stolous, but it seems not to work. I've updated my question.

Comment: Try to create `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-GT-S5230.rules` containing `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="X", ATTR{idProduct}="Y", SYMLINK="GT-S5230"` (where X and Y are found with dmesg for example: `dmesg | tail -n30` just after you plugged in your phone. Then reload udev rules configuration: `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

Comment: It seems not to work. I've created the file with the correct vendor and product IDs, but the output of `simple-mtpfs` is the same (I've checked only Media player mode).

Answer (score 1):

#### Another totaly different solution (Using ADB)

If you are in a hurry then this may be faster than configuring MTP (This may however be less practical if you plan on using this system very often).

1. Install Android SDK tools: `yum install android-tools` (or download it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html))
2. Enable ADB on your phone (`Setting/Developpers Options/Android Debug Bridge`, `USB Debugging`, or something similar) and connect it via USB.

   [image: Enabling USB Debugging]
3. Run `adb devices`. You should see your device here (You may also have to accept the connection on your phone).

---

If you don't then you can also connect via TCP/IP if your phone support it (you have to configure it in the developpers options on your phone) using `adb connect IP`.

---

4. You can now run `adb pull /sdcard/myfile ~/myandroidfiles/myfile` in order to get your file(s) and `adb push ~/myotherfile /sdcard/myotherfile` to transfer a file from your computer to your phone.

Comment: Thanks, @Stolous, but I haven't seen any "ADB option" in my phone (maybe it's enabled by default and not made available to user?). When it comes to `android-tools`, I've updated my question (UPDATE 6).

Comment: Is it _USB Debugging_ maybe ? I've updated my answer. It's normal if you can't see your phone using ADB on your computer because you didn't activate this option on your phone.

Comment: My phone model is rather an old one, first presented on 2009 (Samsung Avila, or Samsung Star, http://www.samsung.com/pl/consumer/mobile-devices/other-phones/others/GT-S5230LKAPLS/). It hasn't such advanced options. I suppose it's operating system is Android-based, not "Android" itself (the best I could find, "proprietary", http://www.phonemore.com/samsung-star-gt-s5230/specs/503).