# How to get the Samsung Galaxy S5 to work with MTP on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, usb, file-copy, android, mtp

So I'm trying to share files between the Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android and my Debian9/KDE machine using MTP instead of KDE Connect.

The problem is that I keep getting:

> The process for the mtp protocol died unexpectedly.

When trying to copy over files.

It also often says

> No Storages found. Maybe you need to unlock your device?

I can view some of the phone's contents in dolphin after trying for a while: pressing "Allow" whenever the dialog on the phone asks for it while trying to open it in dolphin which correctly detects it as Samsung Galaxy S5.

I once could successfully copy over a bunch of images.

I already tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libmtp-common`. syslog has things like the following:

```
usb 1-5: usbfs: process 7907 (mtp.so) did not claim interface 0 before use
usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-5: usbfs: process 7909 (mtp.so) did not claim interface 0 before use
colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 35
usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-5: usbfs: process 7930 (mtp.so) did not claim interface 0 before use
usb 1-5: usbfs: process 7930 (mtp.so) did not claim interface 0 before use
usb 1-5: usbfs: process 7930 (mtp.so) did not claim interface 0 before use
```

Comment: The problem with `MTP` is that some phones, perhaps especially those from Samsung, implement MTP in incompatible ways. Some comments (and links) from another [samsung-device-related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385268/access-files-on-samsung-gt-s5230-avila) on this site may be useful. And GAD3R's answer is worth a try too (`jmtpfs`).

Comment: You can not forget: "the device's screen needs to be unlocked (for security reasons)". That's the point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the `jmtpfs` package

```
apt install jmtpfs
```

Edit your `/etc/fuse.conf` as follows

```
# Allow non-root users to specify the allow_other or allow_root mount options.

user_allow_other
```

Create an udev rule. Use `lsusb` or `mtp-detect` to get the ID of your device

```
nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

with the following line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0666", OWNER="[username]"
```

Replace `04e8` and `6860` with yours , then run:

```
udevadm control --reload
```

Reconnect your device , open the terminal and run:

```
mkdir ~/mtp
jmtpfs ~/mtp
ls ~/mtp
```

sample output:

```
Card  Phone
```

To unmount your device use the following command:

```
fusermount -u ~/mtp
```

Also you can use the [`go-mtpfs`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/go-mtpfs) tool:

> Mount MTP devices over FUSE

```
mkdir ~/mtp
go-mtpfs ~/mtp
```

A graphical tool to mount your device : [`gmtp`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gmtp):

> simple file transfer program for MTP based devices

```
sudo apt install gmtp
gmtp
```

[kio-mtp](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/kio-mtp)

> access to MTP devices for applications using the KDE Platform

Comment: Great - thank you; but [is there also a way to do this without having to add 'user_allow_other' to /etc/fuse.conf (for security)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390221/alternative-to-adding-user-allow-other-to-etc-fuse-conf-for-security)

Comment: I really would love to mark your answer as the solution but it simply does not work for me. I hence had to use KDE Connect. After having to rerun commands many times I get errors incl: `jmtpfs ~/mtp2` `ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface  
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device` `ls: cannot access '/home/username/mtp': Input/output error` `fusermount: failed to unmount /home/username/mtp: Device or resource busy`. Once `ls ~/mtp` showed the right thing and once I could view the files on the SD card in dolphin.

Comment: use jmtpfs /tmp/myphone instead of mounting in ~/mtp, if you got "bad mount point error"