# Alternative to adding 'user_allow_other' to /etc/fuse.conf for security?

Tags: debian, permissions, mount, root, fuse

It looks like [for mounting my Android phone I need to add](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389952/how-to-get-the-samsung-galaxy-s5-to-work-with-mtp-on-debian-9) `user_allow_other` to `/etc/fuse.conf`.

I researched what this does:

According to [the manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/fuse/mount.fuse.8.en.html):

> **user_allow_other**
>   Allow non-root users to specify the *allow_other* or *allow_root* mount options (see below).

&

> **allow_other**
>   This option overrides the security measure restricting file access to the user mounting the filesystem. So all users (including root) can access the files. This option is by default only allowed to root, but this restriction can be removed with a configuration option described in the previous section.

And according to [this](http://www.experts123.com/q/whats-this-about-fuse.conf-and-user_allow_other.html):

> It simply allows individual filesystem implementations to request that other users be allowed access

---

So it looks like it's a security feature which I don't want to just bypass.

I'd like to know whether it can also be a security feature for single-user personal computers. For example by preventing non-root (non-physical) users from gaining access to encrypted VeraCrypt volumes when they get mounted or making the security measure restricting file access more vulnerable in general.

**Is there an alternative to this?** (For mounting Android devices, not alternatives like using external storage devices such as SD cards or KDE Connect for the exchange of data.) For example by only allowing non-root users to specify the allow_root option or by only it allowing it once for a specific action or by using sudo or specifying specific users at some point?